# using sed in Makefile.am (autotools)

Tags: makefile, autotools

I'm packaging up a program using autotools (which I don't have much experience with).

I have a gnome .desktop file that references the location of the executable and the icon.
This needs to be `/usr/share` or `/usr/local/share` depending upon the `@PREFIX@`.
How can I run `sed` on this file in the `data/Makefile.am` so that the installed file works no mater what the `@PREFIX@` is configured to?

My `Makefile.am` is pretty simple at the moment ..

```
wombatdir = $(prefix)/share/
wombat_DATA = applications/wombat.desktop pixmaps/wombat.svg
```

Michael

Answer (score 0):

This is about what I would do.

In `configure.ac`, add `AC_PROG_SED`.

In `Makefile.am`, add

```
[…]
xdgdesktopdir = $(datadir)/applications
pixmapsdir    = $(datadir)/pixmaps

SED_CMDS  =
SED_CMDS += 's|[@]bindir@|$(bindir)|g'
SED_CMDS += 's|[@]pixmapsdir@|$(pixmapsdir)|g'

xdgdesktop_DATA += wombat.desktop
EXTRA_DIST      += wombat.desktop.in
CLEANFILES      += wombat.desktop
wombat.desktop: wombat.desktop.in Makefile
        $(SED) $(SED_CMDS) $(srcdir)/wombat.desktop.in > wombat.desktop
[…]
```

Then rename your `wombat.desktop` to `wombat.desktop.in` and write

```
[…]
Exec=@bindir@/wombat
Icon=@pixmapsdir@/wombat.svg
[…]
```

(not sure whether pixmaps/ is the correct place to install an SVG file, though)

`wombat.desktop.in` will be version controlled. `wombat.desktop` will not be version controlled, and might very well be added to `.gitignore`:

```
/data/wombat.desktop
```